# Curious if this is possible with a Regex replacement

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to figure out a regex pattern to use with the Java `String.replaceAll()` function.  I need to replace all the `%26` but I don't want it to pick up any other numbers with a **'26'** prefix.

For example I want:

```
"abc%26def".replaceAll(regex, "&") to return "abc&def"
```

- and -

```
"abc%2623def".replaceAll(regex, "&") to return "abc%2623def"  (no change)
```

I'm aware I can easily write a few more lines of code to accomplish this task but I was wondering if it's possible to do this with just a single replaceAll.

Comment: I don't now what you are trying to do, but if it's what I think it is, I would not use a regex, I would rather use `URLDecoder.decode(yourString, "UTF-8")`

Comment: @jlordo: That actually doesn't quite work, because it still converts `%2623` to `&23` which is not the OP's desired behavior: http://ideone.com/WwnqzG

Comment: @mellamokb you're right. Question would be better if OP stated why he needed that kind of behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [**negative lookahead assertion**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that prevents matches where `%26` is followed by another digit (you'll need to escape the `\` in Java, so it would be `\\d`):

```
%26(?!\d)
```

- Regex Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/J07zojxabd
- Java Demo: http://ideone.com/luCmFN

Comment: I've never seen lookaheads before.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve this using negative lookahead. From the [manual](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

```
(?!X)   X, via zero-width negative lookahead
```

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be doing decoding of percent-encoded octets, in which case you might want to look at `URLDecoder.decode`:

```
System.out.println(URLDecoder.decode("abc%26def", "UTF-8")
```

This may or may not work for your purposes, as it also translates `+` to a space.

Comment: This actually doesn't quite work, because it still converts `%2623` to `&23` which is not the OP's desired behavior: http://ideone.com/WwnqzG

Comment: True, but still... OP appears to be looking for a tool to do percent-decoding, in which case I think they should at least look at utilities specifically designed for that instead of doing a homebrew regex solution. Maybe OP's desired behavior is incorrect :)